# .load() script won't run inside of previously loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies in advanced for the confusing phrasing!

I'm using .load() for a lot of my content.  Loads within loads in several cases.  This is all functions fine, what I'm struggling with is having nested content loaded along with the parent.

This is the basic function I need to happen:

```
$('.content').ready(function() {        
  $('.r_content').load('r_time.html .r_content');
});
```

How can I make script work on previously loaded content?  I've had to change the syntax before to make scripts run for loaded content, but I can't seem to make this one work

Hopefully that wasn't too confusing.  Thanks!

basic html structure:

```
<body>
    title

    <div class="content">
    blah blah blah - content to be loaded

        <div class="r_content">
        ... r_content also to be loaded, should be from 'r_time.html' by default
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing. Please, try to explain better. Besides, what is that `event` event you are binding to?

Comment: I think you need *more* code, not less. show what you load initially and then what you want to load within the previously loaded content.

Comment: basically, I just need the r_content to be loaded as the default when the parent element is loaded.  The script I have works when it can bind to the (document).ready, but I can't figure out how to bind it to a section load

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed confusing phrasing and code. If you're trying to 1) load() content and once it's loaded 2) load more content inside of it, you'll need to use callbacks or promises. Here's one way with callbacks that sort of mimics you `$(document).on('event')` code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('.r_content').load('r_time.html .r_content', function(){
         $(document).trigger('loadmorestuff'); // things are loaded, tell the document
    });

    // listen for the event 'loadmorestuff' and then run this function.
    $(document).on('loadmorestuff', function (){ 
      $('.the-previously-loaded-container-you-want-to-target').load('r_time.html .r_content');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Looks like you've edited the question a bit. The problem you're running into is that the `ready` event only fires ones. When it fires, the content from your first `load` call doesn't exist yet so the js being run on ready has nothing to run it on. In the example I posted above, the 'ready' event is replaced by a custom event called `loadmorestuff`. You can name it whatever you like. The point is that the `document` is listening for that event with `$(document).on('loadmorestuff'` and you only trigger that event once you're `load()` is finished.

Check out jquery docs for more on the [`load()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) and the [`trigger()` method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: ehh I think it's simpler - mostly just a syntax thing.  I rewrote the question to make a little more sense (*hopefully*).  Basically, I just need the script to run for loaded content.  I know in the past that .on() can be used, but I can't seem to get that to work for me here